# GWT Compile Issues in Java (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Im having a weird compile issue using the Google App engine in java using eclipse. When I try to GWT Compile my code I get an error that is as follows:

```
Compiling module beer.SQLBeer
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Mark/workspace/SQLBeer/src/beer/client/SQLBeer.java'
         [ERROR] Line 12: The import com.google.appengine.api.rdbms cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 13: The import com.google.apphosting cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 14: The import com.google.cloud cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 18: ServersServlet cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 22: The method doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) of type SQLBeer must override or implement a supertype method
         [ERROR] Line 26: Connection cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 28: AppEngineDriver cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 29: Connection cannot be resolved to a type
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'beer.client.SQLBeer'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
Exception in thread "UnitWriteThread"
```

I am not sure why it cannot resolve the imports, and this is preventing me from deploying my code onto the Google app engine. I feel because it is not playing nicely with my imports its the same reason im getting the error

```
[ERROR] Line 22: The method doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) of type SQLBeer must override or implement a supertype method
```

I am really new to using GWT and the Google App Engine for Eclipse, but im trying to access a database my team created using Google Cloud SQL. And I feel Like im getting close, if i can over come these errors.

The Project Code

```
package beer.client;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver;
import com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ServersServlet;
import com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SQLBeer extends ServersServlet {


    @Override 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
            c = (Connection) DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://asu.edu:cst433team1:team1db/mysql");
            String fname = req.getParameter("fname");
            String content = req.getParameter("content");

            /**
             * This code appears to do the web form fun
             */
//          if (fname == "" || content == "") {
//              out.println("<html><head></head><body>You are missing either a message or a name! Try again! Redirecting in 3 seconds...</body></html>");
//          } else {
//              String statement = "INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) VALUES( ? , ? )";
//              PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(statement);
//              stmt.setString(1, fname);
//              stmt.setString(2, content);
//              int success = 2;
//              success = stmt.executeUpdate();
//              if (success == 1) {
//                  out.println("<html><head></head><body>Success! Redirecting in 3 seconds...</body></html>");
//              } else if (success == 0) {
//                  out.println("<html><head></head><body>Failure! Please try again! Redirecting in 3 seconds...</body></html>");
//              }
//          }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                try {
                    c.close();
                } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                }
        }
        //resp.setHeader("Refresh", "3; url=/beer.jsp");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Any Suggestion on what I could do to fix these errors? Ive tried different Imports but they all seem to lead to the same issues in the GWT Compiler.

EDIT: I changed the extend to HttpServlet and now the error is a little different

```
Compiling module beer.SQLBeer
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Mark/workspace/SQLBeer/src/beer/client/SQLBeer.java'
         [ERROR] Line 13: The import com.google.appengine.api.rdbms cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 14: The import com.google.cloud cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 26: Connection cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 28: AppEngineDriver cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 29: Connection cannot be resolved to a type
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'beer.client.SQLBeer'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
Exception in thread "UnitWriteThread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check that this isn't  a classpath issue - meaning you don't have all the required jars in the lib directory and on the classpath.

If that fails, make sure that this code isn't Client side(guessing from your package name), which will gets compiled to javascript. You dont want this to happen for database connection code so you should use this code on the server side.

See the Documentation on [Client side](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsClient.html) & [Server side](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideServerSide) code.

Comment: I see! I was creating server type code the whole time and I thought it was client based. Cant you tell im a novice? :) Now i just have to figure out my issues with JSP's and queries... Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Keep experimenting and keep learning. 
When you're stuck, just ask! Thats the way of SO!